# using command line in terminal I need to create a list of all files name, date created & date modified

Tags: command-line, terminal, command

My command line is very rusty so any help appreciated.

I have cd into the drive. 
touch newfile.txt

now how do I echo the names, date created and date modified into newfile.txt?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to 'touch newfile.txt' as shell stdout redirect can create a file if it doesn't exist (assuming you have the permissions in that directory).

To get the data, you can use the 'stat' command - e.g.:

```
cd /path/to/some/directory
stat -f %N,%c,%m * > newfile.txt
```

If you need the timestamps in a human-friendly output, you can try:

```
stat -f %N,%Sc,%Sm * > newfile.txt
```

Refer to the man page of stat for other options.